# Scroll To Top Button using Vanilla JS Issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a **Scroll To Top Button using Vanilla JS** but I get some errors in my dev console.

I already have a **jQuery** code but I want to convert it to **vanilla js**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

**Here is my Vanilla JS Code:**

```
var backToTopBtn = document.getElementById("backToTopBtn");
backToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
   window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
});
```

**Here is my jQuery Code:**

```
var scrollTop = function (){
    'use strict';
    var scrollTop = jQuery("button.scroltop");
    /* page scroll top on click function */ 
    scrollTop.on('click',function() {
        jQuery("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    })

    jQuery(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 900) {
            jQuery("button.scroltop").fadeIn(1000);
        } else {
            jQuery("button.scroltop").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="scroltop"></button>
```

Comment: Your jQuery code `var scrollTop = jQuery("backToTopBtn");` is using an invalid selector. So I can hardly believe that's the exact code you used. And why than suddenly a bit later this `jQuery("button.scroltop")`?

Comment: I want to use the same code with vanilla js

Comment: Than use `document.querySelector("backToTopBtn")` if you want to get that invalid element selector - which refers to the invalid element tag `<backToTopBtn></backToTopBtn>`

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: how I can fix this issue ?

Comment: Your error means exactly as it reads: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"* that means you're doing basically `undefined.addEventListener(`... which means either 1. you don't have any `#backToTopBtn`element. 2. you're not using your `<script>` tags where due, and that's right **before the closing `</body>` tag.** (unless you use the `deferred` script attribute...)

Comment: my vanilla js code for scroll to top button not completed I want to display the button only in specific size 350

Comment: Which means that the scrolling actually works? That's not possible if you got the error you said you got. Fix that error first as I explained. Use a proper ID. And make sure to place the `<script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: how can I add that ?

Comment: <button type="button" class="scroltop" id="backToTopBtn">A value as well hey?</button>

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to select an element in the document to add an event listener to it (`document.getElementById("backToTopBtn")`), but this element doesn't exist.

Add `id="backToTopBtn"` to your button.

```js
var backToTopBtn = document.getElementById("backToTopBtn");
backToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

#backToTopBtn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="scroltop" id="backToTopBtn">Top</button>
</div>
```